# Clearing Duplicates and Comparing count versus field Value T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with Two tables and I've joined them together. I'm almost done with the query, but I'm not sure how to proceed further.

There are two tables:

1. Person - Table that contains records of people participating in the Pen Pal program
2. Contact - Table that contains contact records.

The Person table has a type field that determines if they're class 1 or class 2 (noted by "O" or "I")

So Far the query is this:

```
select p.PersonId as PersonTableID,
       c.InmateId as ContactTableId,
       p.PersonName,
       p.Country,
       p.MaxContactNum as MaxContacts,
       p.Type as PersonType,
       c.CorrespId,
       c.LastUpdateDate,
       p.language,
       (select count(InmateId)
       from tblcfContacts
       where InmateId=p.PersonId) as ContactCount,
       case
        when (select count(InmateId)
                from tblcfContacts
                where InmateId=p.PersonId or CorrespId=p.PersonId) > p.MaxContactNum
            then 'Too Many'
        when (select count(InmateId)
                from tblcfContacts
                where InmateId=p.PersonId or CorrespId=p.PersonId) = p.MaxContactNum
            then 'Just Right'
        when (select count(InmateId)
                from tblcfContacts
                where InmateId=p.PersonId or CorrespId=p.PersonId) < p.MaxContactNum
            then 'Room For More'
       end as ContactStatus
    from tblCfPerson as p 
    inner join tblCfContacts as c 
    on p.PersonId=c.InmateId or p.PersonId=c.CorrespId where p.Country='CA'
```

The Query is returning results like this:

[image]

As you can see, there are duplicates, and the comparison between the Maximum Contact Field and Assigned Contacts is a bit off.

How can I only see one row per person and fix the Contact Count Calculation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you only see one row then which row do you want to see when some columns have different values?

Comment: that's the thing, we're not looking at the different contact connections, we're only interested in the existence of a connection. (also this DB was poorly designed. relations are manually done through queries in the overlaid app.)

Comment: They have different ContractTableID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to show the columns from the `tblCfContacts` table, you should remove the `JOIN` with this table. Also, using a `CROSS APPLY` would help to write a shorter query:

```
select p.PersonId as PersonTableID,
       p.PersonName,
       p.Country,
       p.MaxContactNum as MaxContacts,
       p.Type as PersonType,
       p.language,
       x.ContactCount,
       case
        when x.ContactCount > p.MaxContactNum then 'Too Many'
        when x.ContactCount = p.MaxContactNum then 'Just Right'
        when x.ContactCount < p.MaxContactNum then 'Room For More'
       end as ContactStatus
from tblCfPerson as p 
CROSS APPLY (
    select count(InmateId) AS ContactCount
    from tblcfContacts c
    where c.InmateId=p.PersonId or c.CorrespId=p.PersonId)
) x
where p.Country='CA'
```

Comment: I like, but I'm going to need more fields. Good thing they're on the person table.

Answer (score 0):

The ContactTableId is creating unique rows for every PersonTableID.  If the field "ContactTableId" is not necessary to the output of the report, remove it and you'll remove the duplicate PersonTableID rows.  However, it seems useful information to note that a PersonTableID can have more than one ContactTableId.

Or to put it plainly (if I'm inferring the context correctly) each Person is writing to multiple Inmates.